# How can I "jobify" my pathfinding script using the Unity Job System if it contains Lists?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a pathfinding script that works wonderfully.

I can run it on 20k units at around 15 FPS. However, pathfinding is going to be (and already is) the bottleneck of my game, CPU-wise. That is why I want to take advantage of all my cores using the Unity Job system.

I've come to the conclusion it is just not "jobifyable" but before scrapping everything I want to have your input.

Here is the thing I want to "jobify":

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class pfMain : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Transform capsule;
    private List<Capsule> capsuleList;

    private List<Vector3> screenPos;
    [HideInInspector] public int pathDis;
    private int itineraryLength;
    [HideInInspector] public int oriItineraryLength;
    [HideInInspector] public float speed;
    [HideInInspector] public LayerMask _obstacle;

    public class Capsule
    {
        public Transform transform;
        public List<Vector3> itinerary;
        public List<Vector3> surroundingPos;
        public List<float> surroundingCost;
        public float smallestFcost;
        public bool itineraryEmpty;
        public Vector3 startPos;
        public Vector3 targetPos;
        public Vector3 destinationPos;
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        capsuleList = new List<Capsule>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 20000; i++)
        {
            Vector3 startPos = new Vector3(UnityEngine.Random.Range(40, 200), 1f, UnityEngine.Random.Range(-90, 30));
            Vector3 destination = new Vector3(UnityEngine.Random.Range(-470, -440), 1f, UnityEngine.Random.Range(-90, 30));
            Transform capsuleTransform = Instantiate(capsule, startPos, Quaternion.identity);
            capsuleList.Add(new Capsule
            {
                transform = capsuleTransform,
                startPos = startPos,
                destinationPos = destination,
                targetPos = startPos,
                itinerary = new List<Vector3>(),
                surroundingPos = new List<Vector3>(),
                surroundingCost = new List<float>(),
                itineraryEmpty = true,
                smallestFcost = 999f,

            });
        }

        speed = 5f;
        pathDis = 3;
        oriItineraryLength = 40;
        itineraryLength = oriItineraryLength;
        _obstacle = 8;
        screenPos = new List<Vector3>()
        {
            new Vector3 (-pathDis, 0f, -pathDis),
            new Vector3(-pathDis, 0f, 0f),
            new Vector3(-pathDis, 0f, pathDis),
            new Vector3(0f, 0f, -pathDis),
            new Vector3(0f, 0f, pathDis),
            new Vector3(pathDis, 0f, -pathDis),
            new Vector3(pathDis, 0f, 0f),
            new Vector3(pathDis, 0f, pathDis)
        };
    }


    private void Update()
    {
        foreach (Capsule capsule in capsuleList)
        {
            capsule.startPos = capsule.transform.position;
            if (capsule.startPos != capsule.destinationPos && capsule.itineraryEmpty == true)
            {
                pathfinding(capsule);
            }
            if (capsule.itineraryEmpty == false)
            {
                capsule.targetPos = capsule.itinerary[0];
                obstructionCheck(capsule);
                if (capsule.targetPos == capsule.startPos)
                {
                    capsule.itinerary.Remove(capsule.targetPos);
                    if (capsule.itinerary.Count == 0)
                    {
                        capsule.itineraryEmpty = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            capsule.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(capsule.startPos, capsule.targetPos, speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
    private void pathfinding(Capsule capsule)
    {
        Vector3 oriPos = capsule.startPos;
        for (int i = 0; i < itineraryLength; i++)
        {

            for (int h = 0; h < screenPos.Count; h++)
            {
                Vector3 neighborPos = oriPos + screenPos[h];
                if (Physics.Linecast(oriPos, neighborPos, _obstacle) || capsule.itinerary.Contains(neighborPos))
                {
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    Vector3 destDirection = capsule.destinationPos - neighborPos;

                    float Hcost = Mathf.Pow((destDirection.x * destDirection.x) + (destDirection.z * destDirection.z), 0.5f);

                    capsule.surroundingPos.Add(neighborPos);
                    capsule.surroundingCost.Add(Hcost);
                    continue;
                }
            }
            for (int h = 0; h < capsule.surroundingPos.Count; h++)
            {
                if (capsule.surroundingCost[h] < capsule.smallestFcost)
                {
                    capsule.smallestFcost = capsule.surroundingCost[h];
                    oriPos = capsule.surroundingPos[h];
                }
            }
            capsule.itinerary.Add(oriPos);
            capsule.surroundingPos.Clear();
            capsule.surroundingCost.Clear();
            capsule.smallestFcost = 999f;
            if (!Physics.Linecast(capsule.itinerary[capsule.itinerary.Count - 1], capsule.destinationPos, _obstacle))
            {
                capsule.itinerary.Add(capsule.destinationPos);
                break;
            }
        }
        longPathCheck(capsule);
        cleanUp(capsule);
        capsule.itineraryEmpty = false;
    }
    private void obstructionCheck(Capsule capsule)
    {
        if (Physics.Linecast(capsule.startPos, capsule.itinerary[0], _obstacle))
        {
            capsule.itinerary.Clear();
            capsule.targetPos = capsule.startPos;
            capsule.itineraryEmpty = true;
        }
    }
    private void longPathCheck(Capsule capsule)
    {
        if (capsule.itinerary.Count >= itineraryLength)
        {
            Vector3 oriDir = capsule.destinationPos - capsule.itinerary[0];
            Vector3 finDir = capsule.destinationPos - capsule.itinerary[capsule.itinerary.Count - 2];
            float oriDis = Mathf.Pow((oriDir.x * oriDir.x) + (oriDir.z * oriDir.z), 0.5f);
            float finDis = Mathf.Pow((finDir.x * finDir.x) + (finDir.z * finDir.z), 0.5f);
            if (oriDis - finDis < (pathDis * itineraryLength) / 2)
            {
                itineraryLength = oriItineraryLength * 10;
            }
            else
            {
                itineraryLength = oriItineraryLength;
            }
        }
    }
    private void cleanUp(Capsule capsule)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < capsule.itinerary.Count - 2; i++)
        {
            for (int h = 0; i < capsule.itinerary.Count - 2; h++)
            {
                if (!Physics.Linecast(capsule.itinerary[i], capsule.itinerary[i + 2], _obstacle))
                {
                    capsule.itinerary.Remove(capsule.itinerary[i + 1]);
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So far my attempts led to many errors that I can't even hope to comprehend.

One of these seems to refer to the lists I use in my method when I tried to put them in `NativeArray` of `NativeList`.

Now my question for you is: By looking quickly at my code, can you tell me if it's even "jobifyable"?

Is there anything that cannot be "jobified" that I should know about?

Here is my latest attempt to jobify my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Unity.Collections;
using Unity.Jobs;
using Unity.Mathematics;
using UnityEngine;

public class pfJobs : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Transform capsule;
    private List<Capsule> capsuleList;

    public class Capsule
    {
        public Transform transform;
        public NativeList<float3> itinerary;
        public NativeList<float3> surroundingPos;
        public NativeList<float> surroundingCost;
        public float smallestFcost;
        public bool itineraryEmpty;
        public float3 startPos;
        public float3 targetPos;
        public float3 destinationPos;
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        capsuleList = new List<Capsule>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 20000; i++)
        {
            float3 startPos = new float3(UnityEngine.Random.Range(40, 200), 1f, UnityEngine.Random.Range(-90, 30));
            float3 destination = new float3(UnityEngine.Random.Range(-470, -440), 1f, UnityEngine.Random.Range(-90, 30));
            Transform capsuleTransform = Instantiate(capsule, startPos, Quaternion.identity);
            capsuleList.Add(new Capsule
            {
                transform = capsuleTransform,
                startPos = startPos,
                destinationPos = destination,
                targetPos = startPos,
                itinerary = new NativeList<float3>(),
                surroundingPos = new NativeList<float3>(),
                surroundingCost = new NativeList<float>(),
                itineraryEmpty = true,
                smallestFcost = 999f,

            });
        }
    }


    private void Update()
    {
        NativeArray<float3> position = new NativeArray<float3>(capsuleList.Count, Allocator.Temp);
        NativeArray<NativeList<float3>> itinerary = new NativeArray<NativeList<float3>>(capsuleList.Count, Allocator.Temp);
        NativeArray<NativeList<float3>> surroundingPos = new NativeArray<NativeList<float3>>(capsuleList.Count, Allocator.Temp);
        NativeArray<NativeList<float>> surroundingCost = new NativeArray<NativeList<float>>(capsuleList.Count, Allocator.Temp);
        NativeArray<float> smallestFcost = new NativeArray<float>(capsuleList.Count, Allocator.Temp);
        NativeArray<bool> itineraryEmpty = new NativeArray<bool>(capsuleList.Count, Allocator.Temp);
        NativeArray<float3> startPos = new NativeArray<float3>(capsuleList.Count, Allocator.Temp);
        NativeArray<float3> targetPos = new NativeArray<float3>(capsuleList.Count, Allocator.Temp);
        NativeArray<float3> destinationPos = new NativeArray<float3>(capsuleList.Count, Allocator.Temp);
        for (int i = 0; i < capsuleList.Count; i++)
        {
            position[i] = capsuleList[i].transform.position;
            itinerary[i] = capsuleList[i].itinerary;
            surroundingPos[i] = capsuleList[i].surroundingPos;
            surroundingCost[i] = capsuleList[i].surroundingCost;
            smallestFcost[i] = capsuleList[i].smallestFcost;
            itineraryEmpty[i] = capsuleList[i].itineraryEmpty;
            startPos[i] = capsuleList[i].startPos;
            targetPos[i] = capsuleList[i].targetPos;
            destinationPos[i] = capsuleList[i].destinationPos;
        }


        PfJob pathfindingJob = new PfJob
        {
            //agent specific
            position = position,
            itinerary = itinerary,
            surroundingPos = surroundingPos,
            surroundingCost = surroundingCost,
            smallestFcost = smallestFcost,
            itineraryEmpty = itineraryEmpty,
            startPos = startPos,
            targetPos = targetPos,
            destinationPos = destinationPos,

            //global variables
            deltaTime = Time.deltaTime,
            pathDis = 5,
            itineraryLength = 40,
            oriItineraryLength = 40,
            speed = 3f,
            _obstacle = 8,
            screenPos = new NativeList<float3>()
            {
                new float3(-5, 0f, -5),
                new float3(-5, 0f, 0f),
                new float3(-5, 0f, 5),
                new float3(0f, 0f, -5),
                new float3(0f, 0f, 5),
                new float3(5, 0f, -5),
                new float3(5, 0f, 0f),
                new float3(5, 0f, 5)
            }
        };
        JobHandle jobHandle = pathfindingJob.Schedule(capsuleList.Count, 2000);
        jobHandle.Complete();
        for (int i = 0; i < capsuleList.Count; i++)
        {
            capsuleList[i].transform.position = position[i];
            capsuleList[i].itinerary = itinerary[i];
            capsuleList[i].surroundingPos = surroundingPos[i];
            capsuleList[i].surroundingCost = surroundingCost[i];
            capsuleList[i].smallestFcost = smallestFcost[i];
            capsuleList[i].itineraryEmpty = itineraryEmpty[i];
            capsuleList[i].startPos = startPos[i];
            capsuleList[i].targetPos = targetPos[i];
            capsuleList[i].destinationPos = destinationPos[i];
        }
        
        position.Dispose();
        itinerary.Dispose();
        surroundingPos.Dispose();
        surroundingCost.Dispose();
        smallestFcost.Dispose();
        itineraryEmpty.Dispose();
        startPos.Dispose();
        targetPos.Dispose();
        destinationPos.Dispose();
        
        /*
        foreach(Capsule capsule in capsuleList)
        {
            capsule.startPos = capsule.transform.position;
            if (capsule.startPos != capsule.destinationPos && capsule.itineraryEmpty == true)
            {
                pathfinding(capsule);
            }
            if (capsule.itineraryEmpty == false)
            {
                capsule.targetPos = capsule.itinerary[0];
                obstructionCheck(capsule);
                if (capsule.targetPos == capsule.startPos)
                {
                    capsule.itinerary.Remove(capsule.targetPos);
                    if (capsule.itinerary.Count == 0)
                    {
                        capsule.itineraryEmpty = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            capsule.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(capsule.startPos, capsule.targetPos, speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        */
    }
}
public struct PfJob : IJobParallelFor
{
    /// NATIVEARRAY = agent specific stuff
    public NativeArray<float3> position;

    public NativeArray<NativeList<float3>> itinerary;
    public NativeArray<NativeList<float3>> surroundingPos;
    public NativeArray<NativeList<float>> surroundingCost;

    public NativeArray<float> smallestFcost;
    public NativeArray<bool> itineraryEmpty;
    public NativeArray<float3> startPos;
    public NativeArray<float3> targetPos;
    public NativeArray<float3> destinationPos;

    /// OTHER COMMON VARIABLES
    public NativeList<float3> screenPos;
    public int pathDis;
    public int itineraryLength;
    public int oriItineraryLength;
    public float speed;
    public LayerMask _obstacle;
    public float deltaTime;


    
    public void Execute(int index)
    {
        startPos[index] = position[index];
        if (!startPos[index].Equals(destinationPos[index]) && itineraryEmpty[index] == true)
        {
            /// PATHFINDING ///
            float3 oriPos = startPos[index];
            for (int i = 0; i < itinerary[index].Length; i++)
            {

                for (int h = 0; h < screenPos.Length; h++)
                {
                    float3 neighborPos = oriPos + screenPos[h];
                    if (Physics.Linecast(oriPos, neighborPos, _obstacle) || itinerary[index].Contains(neighborPos))
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        float3 destDirection = destinationPos[index] - neighborPos;

                        float Hcost = math.pow((destDirection.x * destDirection.x) + (destDirection.z * destDirection.z), 0.5f);
                        surroundingPos[index].Add(neighborPos);
                        surroundingCost[index].Add(Hcost);
                        continue;
                    }
                }
                for (int h = 0; h < surroundingPos[index].Length; h++)
                {
                    if (surroundingCost[index][h] < smallestFcost[index])
                    {
                        smallestFcost[index] = surroundingCost[index][h];
                        oriPos = surroundingPos[index][h];
                    }
                }
                itinerary[index].Add(oriPos);
                surroundingPos[index].Clear();
                surroundingCost[index].Clear();
                smallestFcost[index] = 999f;
                if (!Physics.Linecast(itinerary[index][itinerary[index].Length - 1], destinationPos[index], _obstacle))
                {
                    itinerary[index].Add(destinationPos[index]);
                    break;
                }
            }

            /// LONG PATH CHECK ///
            if (itinerary[index].Length >= itineraryLength)
            {
                float3 oriDir = destinationPos[index] - itinerary[index][0];
                float3 finDir = destinationPos[index] - itinerary[index][itinerary[index].Length - 2];
                float oriDis = math.pow((oriDir.x * oriDir.x) + (oriDir.z * oriDir.z), 0.5f);
                float finDis = math.pow((finDir.x * finDir.x) + (finDir.z * finDir.z), 0.5f);
                if (oriDis - finDis < (pathDis * itineraryLength) / 2)
                {
                    itineraryLength = oriItineraryLength * 10;
                }
                else
                {
                    itineraryLength = oriItineraryLength;
                }
            }
            /// LONG PATH CHECK ///

            /// CLEAN UP ///
            for (int i = 0; i < itinerary[index].Length - 2; i++)
            {
                for (int h = 0; i < itinerary[index].Length - 2; h++)
                {
                    if (!Physics.Linecast(itinerary[index][i], itinerary[index][i + 2], _obstacle))
                    {
                        itinerary[index].RemoveAt(i + 1);
                        continue;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            /// CLEAN UP ///

            itineraryEmpty[index] = false;
            /// PATHFINDING ///
        }
        if (itineraryEmpty[index] == false)
        {
            targetPos[index] = itinerary[index][0];

            /// OBSTRUCTION CHECK ///
            if (Physics.Linecast(startPos[index], itinerary[index][0], _obstacle))
            {
                itinerary[index].Clear();
                targetPos[index] = startPos[index];
                itineraryEmpty[index] = true;
            }
            /// OBSTRUCTION CHECK ///
            
            if (targetPos[index].Equals(startPos[index]))
            {
                itinerary[index].RemoveAt(0);
                if (itinerary[index].Length == 0)
                {
                    itineraryEmpty[index] = true;
                }
            }
        }
        position[index] = Vector3.MoveTowards(startPos[index], targetPos[index], speed * deltaTime);
    }
}
```

What I tried: Using the Unity Job system to "jobify" my pathfinding script.

What I expected: I pretty much expected to fail at first but following the errors maybe find a way to make it work. The errors are so cryptic however, and there's so little resource on the subject out there that it makes it impossible for me to progress.

EDIT:
Here is the error I get with the jobified script as it is in the post:

InvalidOperationException: Unity.Collections.NativeList1[Unity.Mathematics.float3] used in NativeArray<Unity.Collections.NativeList1[Unity.Mathematics.float3]> must be unmanaged (contain no managed types) and cannot itself be a native container type. Unity.Collections.NativeArray1[T].IsUnmanagedAndThrow () (at :0) Unity.Collections.NativeArray1[T].CheckAllocateArguments (System.Int32 length, Unity.Collections.Allocator allocator, System.Int64 totalSize) (at :0) Unity.Collections.NativeArray1[T].Allocate (System.Int32 length, Unity.Collections.Allocator allocator, Unity.Collections.NativeArray1[T]& array) (at :0) Unity.Collections.NativeArray`1[T]..ctor (System.Int32 length, Unity.Collections.Allocator allocator, Unity.Collections.NativeArrayOptions options) (at :0) pfJobs.Update () (at Assets/scripts/pfJobs.cs:54)

This seems to refer to my many NativeArray;

When I removed them all from the script just to see if that was the issue, the error won't show anymore but an other error pops:

ObjectDisposedException: The UNKNOWN_OBJECT_TYPE has been deallocated, it is not allowed to access it Unity.Collections.LowLevel.Unsafe.AtomicSafetyHandle.CheckWriteAndBumpSecondaryVersion (Unity.Collections.LowLevel.Unsafe.AtomicSafetyHandle handle) (at :0) Unity.Collections.NativeList`1[T].Add (T& value) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.collections@1.2.4/Unity.Collections/NativeList.cs:330) pfJobs.Update () (at Assets/scripts/pfJobs.cs:76)

this one is a complete mystery for me, when double clicked on, it leads to a nativeList script. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: This is not uncommon when trying a whole new thing. However. You failed to include the errors

Comment: hi! thank you for you quick response, you're right I forgot to include them, the errors are now in a new answer bellow. I hope it's less cryptic for you than it is for me!

Comment: I edited the question and I tried to make the tone of the question more neutral. (Anything which is perceived to be ranting can attract down-votes and can be off-putting to the community, making it less likely that you will receive help). It may also help if you can reduce your code to a [mre]. And, as already noted, please delete the non-answer - and, instead, add your new information to the body of your question.

Comment: thanks for the tips, I'm new to stack overflow and its culture and this will help for future post, I'm currently working on a more comprehensible, simplified example. For this post I will make the appropriated edit, thanks again.

Comment: The error is saying it doesn’t like `NativeArray<NativeList<float3>> itinerary` and the other members like that. Can you flatten those, to make a single array of length the total number of inner lists * known length?

Comment: hi Milan, can you expend on your suggestion? I made a very simplified version of the script to understand the issue better. If I understand the job system correctly, I need to put every variables in arrays so jobs iterate them in parallel on many cores but when it comes to list or other containers, I'm stuck since it doesn't let me put them in arrays! Problem is, Lists have pretty badass function like "Contains", "Add", "Remove" that I depend on since I use them extensively in my code. I really need a workaround but I just can't figure it out. Thanks for the help!